# 2つのDataframeで期間重複するIDを抽出したい

Tags: python, pandas

python3とpandasを使っています。
df1,df2の2つのDataframeのうち同じIDの人物の日付を比較し、期間重複がある行のIDを取り出したいです。
実際には10万行ほどあります。

```py
data1 = [[1, "2010-01-01", "2010-01-20"], [1, "2010-03-20", "2010-03-30"],
        [2, "2010-02-01", "2010-04-20"], [3, "2010-06-10", "2010-06-15"],
        [3, "2010-06-20", "2010-06-30"], [3, "2010-07-10", "2010-06-20"]]

data2 = [[1, "2010-01-15", "2010-01-30"], [1, "2010-04-20", "2010-04-30"],
        [2, "2010-05-01", "2010-05-10"], [2, "2010-05-20", "2010-05-25"],
        [3, "2010-02-01", "2010-02-15"], [3, "2010-06-15", "2010-06-25"]]

columns1 = ["ID", "start_date", "end_date"]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1,columns=columns)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2,columns=columns)
```

これをIDで比較して、下記のようなリストがほしいです。

result_list = [1,3]

```py
result_list = []
for index,row1 in df1.iterrows():
    if not row1["ID"] in result_list:
        for index,row2 in df2.iterrows():
            if row1["ID"] == row2["ID"] and row2["start_date"] <= row1["end_date"] and row2["end_date"] >= row1["start_date"]:
                result_list.append(row1["ID"])
                break
result_list = list(set(result_list))
result_list
```

試行錯誤して，求める結果を得ることができましたが
効率が悪いような気がしてなりません…多重for文を書かずに済む方法はないものでしょうか．
アドバイス宜しくお願い致します.

Comment: 1つのDataFrameの中での重複は無い前提ですか？　重複があった場合はどうしますか？(1つのDataFrame内でも重複とみなす or 2つのDataFrame間で重複しないと重複とは見なさない)

Answer (score 1):

For 文を pandas で使いたくない派なので、ひたすらデータフレーム処理で重複を求めていくと、次のようになると思います。

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: data1 = [[1, "2010-01-01", "2010-01-20"], [1, "2010-03-20", "2010-03-30"],
      :         [2, "2010-02-01", "2010-04-20"], [3, "2010-06-10", "2010-06-15"],
      :         [3, "2010-06-20", "2010-06-30"], [3, "2010-07-10", "2010-07-20"]]
      :
      : data2 = [[1, "2010-01-15", "2010-01-30"], [1, "2010-04-20", "2010-04-30"],
      :         [2, "2010-05-01", "2010-05-10"], [2, "2010-05-20", "2010-05-25"],
      :         [3, "2010-02-01", "2010-02-15"], [3, "2010-06-15", "2010-06-25"]]
      :
      : columns = ["ID", "start_date", "end_date"]
      :
      : df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1,columns=columns)
      : df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2,columns=columns)

In [3]: df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=["df1", "df2"])
      : df
Out[3]:
       ID  start_date    end_date
df1 0   1  2010-01-01  2010-01-20
    1   1  2010-03-20  2010-03-30
    2   2  2010-02-01  2010-04-20
    3   3  2010-06-10  2010-06-15
    4   3  2010-06-20  2010-06-30
    5   3  2010-07-10  2010-07-20
df2 0   1  2010-01-15  2010-01-30
    1   1  2010-04-20  2010-04-30
    2   2  2010-05-01  2010-05-10
    3   2  2010-05-20  2010-05-25
    4   3  2010-02-01  2010-02-15
    5   3  2010-06-15  2010-06-25

In [4]: stacked = df.set_index("ID", append=True).stack().to_frame()
      : stacked
Out[4]:
                              0
      ID
df1 0 1  start_date  2010-01-01
         end_date    2010-01-20
    1 1  start_date  2010-03-20
         end_date    2010-03-30
    2 2  start_date  2010-02-01
         end_date    2010-04-20
    3 3  start_date  2010-06-10
         end_date    2010-06-15
    4 3  start_date  2010-06-20
         end_date    2010-06-30
    5 3  start_date  2010-07-10
         end_date    2010-07-20
df2 0 1  start_date  2010-01-15
         end_date    2010-01-30
    1 1  start_date  2010-04-20
         end_date    2010-04-30
    2 2  start_date  2010-05-01
         end_date    2010-05-10
    3 2  start_date  2010-05-20
         end_date    2010-05-25
    4 3  start_date  2010-02-01
         end_date    2010-02-15
    5 3  start_date  2010-06-15
         end_date    2010-06-25

In [5]: ordered = stacked.reset_index(level=2).sort_values(['ID', 0])
      : ordered
Out[5]:
                  ID           0
df1 0 start_date   1  2010-01-01
df2 0 start_date   1  2010-01-15
df1 0 end_date     1  2010-01-20
df2 0 end_date     1  2010-01-30
df1 1 start_date   1  2010-03-20
      end_date     1  2010-03-30
df2 1 start_date   1  2010-04-20
      end_date     1  2010-04-30
df1 2 start_date   2  2010-02-01
      end_date     2  2010-04-20
df2 2 start_date   2  2010-05-01
      end_date     2  2010-05-10
    3 start_date   2  2010-05-20
      end_date     2  2010-05-25
    4 start_date   3  2010-02-01
      end_date     3  2010-02-15
df1 3 start_date   3  2010-06-10
      end_date     3  2010-06-15
df2 5 start_date   3  2010-06-15
df1 4 start_date   3  2010-06-20
df2 5 end_date     3  2010-06-25
df1 4 end_date     3  2010-06-30
    5 start_date   3  2010-07-10
      end_date     3  2010-07-20

In [14]: seq_df = ordered[["ID"]].reset_index()[["level_2", "ID"]].pipe(
       :     lambda df:
       :     df.assign(
       :         prev_level_2=df.groupby("ID").shift()
       :     )
       : )
       : seq_df
Out[14]:
       level_2  ID prev_level_2
0   start_date   1          NaN
1   start_date   1   start_date
2     end_date   1   start_date
3     end_date   1     end_date
4   start_date   1     end_date
5     end_date   1   start_date
6   start_date   1     end_date
7     end_date   1   start_date
8   start_date   2          NaN
9     end_date   2   start_date
10  start_date   2     end_date
11    end_date   2   start_date
12  start_date   2     end_date
13    end_date   2   start_date
14  start_date   3          NaN
15    end_date   3   start_date
16  start_date   3     end_date
17    end_date   3   start_date
18  start_date   3     end_date
19  start_date   3   start_date
20    end_date   3   start_date
21    end_date   3     end_date
22  start_date   3     end_date
23    end_date   3   start_date

In [15]: overlap_df = seq_df.pipe(
       :     lambda df:
       :     df[df["level_2"] == df["prev_level_2"]]
       : )
       : overlap_df
Out[15]:
       level_2  ID prev_level_2
1   start_date   1   start_date
3     end_date   1     end_date
19  start_date   3   start_date
21    end_date   3     end_date

In [16]: overlap_df["ID"].unique()
Out[16]: array([1, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

**再検討：**
その後、高速化の記事など眺めながら考えていて、「多重for文を書かない」というか、それに類似するであろう「ループを書かない」前提条件を思いっきり無視し、かつ全然簡潔では無い内容ですが、頭の体操みたいなものとして、高速化は出来るだろう処理を作ってみました。

こんな考え方にしています。

・データは`ID`を1番目、`start_date`を2番目のキーとしてソート済みであることを前提にする
・1つのDataFrameの中では重複は無いものとする
・メインの処理では pandas は使わず、Python基本のリストを使う
・`ID`や`start_date`, `end_date`の範囲をチェックし、不要な範囲での重複検出ループを回さない

チェック前のデータを(csv等で?)作成する時点であらかじめソートしておくくらいは前提として許されるのでは？
一応以下の2行を呼び出せば出来ますが、それはそれで時間とメモリがかかるので。
プロファイラではかると、約 4.5ms, 0.406MiB 程度かかっていました。

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(['ID','start_date'])
df2 = df2.sort_values(['ID','start_date'])
```

そして以下が重複検出処理です。以下の全部で、約 1ms弱, 0.078MiB 程度かかっていました。

```
# pandas DataFrame から Python基本のリストへ
#
df1limit = len(df1)
df2limit = len(df2)
df1ID = df1['ID'].tolist()
df1start = df1['start_date'].tolist()
df1end = df1['end_date'].tolist()
df2ID = df2['ID'].tolist()
df2start = df2['start_date'].tolist()
df2end = df2['end_date'].tolist()

# メインの重複検出処理
#
result_list = []
df1index = 0
df2index = 0
while df1index < df1limit:
  CurrentID = df1ID[df1index]

  # df1 と df2 で比較開始時の'ID'が同じになるようにリストのインデックスを調整
  #
  df2IDFounded = False
  while df2index < df2limit:
    if CurrentID > df2ID[df2index]:  # df2 の方の'ID'が小さいので読み飛ばし
      df2index += 1
    else:
      if CurrentID == df2ID[df2index]:
        df2IDFounded = True
      break
  else:
    break  # df2 が終わったので検出処理終了

  if not df2IDFounded:  # df1 と同じ'ID'が df2 に無ければ、df1 の'ID'を読み飛ばす
    while df1index < df1limit and CurrentID == df1ID[df1index]:
      df1index += 1
    continue

  # 日付比較して重複検出する処理
  #
  df2compareTop = df2index  # df2 の同じ'ID'の先頭インデックスをセーブ
  DuplicateFounded = False  # 重複検出フラグクリア

  while df1index < df1limit and CurrentID == df1ID[df1index]:  # df1 の'ID'が同じ間はループ
    StartDate1 = df1start[df1index]  # df1 の比較用日付をリストから取得(少しでも時間短縮)
    EndDate1 = df1end[df1index]      #   〃
    df2index = df2compareTop         # df2 の同じ'ID'の先頭インデックスをリストア

    while df2index < df2limit and CurrentID == df2ID[df2index]:  # df2 の'ID'が同じ間はループ
      if df2start[df2index] <= EndDate1 and df2end[df2index] >= StartDate1:  # 重複検出の比較処理
        result_list.append(CurrentID)  # 重複検出したのでリストへ追加
        DuplicateFounded = True        # 重複検出フラグ設定してループ終了
        break
      elif df2start[df2index] > EndDate1:  # これ以後は重複しないのでループ終了
        break
      else:
        df2index += 1     # df2 の同じ'ID'の次のデータへ
    #
    # df2 との重複検出処理ループの底

    df1index += 1
    if DuplicateFounded:  # 重複検出したのでループ終了して次の'ID'へ
      break
  #
  # df1 の同一'ID'での重複検出処理ループの底

  while df1index < df1limit and CurrentID == df1ID[df1index]:  # df1 の次の'ID'のまで読み飛ばし
    df1index += 1
  while df2index < df2limit and CurrentID == df2ID[df2index]:  # df2 の次の'ID'のまで読み飛ばし
    df2index += 1

# 全部の重複検出処理ループの底

print(result_list)  # 重複'ID'リスト表示
```

---

コメントで聞いておいて答えも待たずに書いてしまいます。
かえって効率が悪いかもだったり、forのネストが深かったりしますが、一応両方思いついたので。

ちなみに、質問記事ソースコードの`data1`の最後`[3, "2010-07-10", "2010-06-20"]`の終了期日は、おそらく`"2010-07-20"`の書き間違いでしょう。
そして`columns1 = ["ID", "start_date", "end_date"]`の変数名も数字の付かない`columns`の書き間違いでしょうね。

---

**「1つのDataFrame内でも重複とみなす」** 方法
参考記事
[pandas Timestampとdate_rangeの使い方](https://qiita.com/u1and0/items/ed37fa4571f327b897e0)
[Python pandas 図でみる データ連結 / 結合処理](http://sinhrks.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/01/28/073327)
[pandas.DataFrame, Seriesの重複した行を抽出・削除](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-duplicated-drop-duplicates/)

あまり洗練されては無さそうな強引な方法です。
ただ、必要ならば全ての重複期間のデータを取得することも出来ます。

- 両方のDataFrameを混ぜてしまう
- 'ID' でグルーピングし、以下を ID 毎に処理する
- 該当期間の1日を1件としてDataFrameに展開して連結する
- pandasの機能を使って1行で重複のチェックと重複件数取得(件数自身には意味なし)
- 重複があれば続けて結果リストにIDを追加する処理が行われる
- 重複が無い場合は例外になってID追加処理が行われないのを利用する、例外は無視する

以下の様な処理になります。

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)

result_list = []
for ID, grp in df3.groupby('ID'):
  arr = []
  for index, item in grp.iterrows():
    arr.append(pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=item['start_date'], end=item['end_date'])))

  arr = pd.concat(arr, ignore_index=True)
  try:
    dup = arr.duplicated().value_counts()[True]
    result_list.append(ID)
  except:
    pass

print(result_list)
```

---

**「2つのDataFrame間で重複しないと重複とは見なさない」** 方法
参考記事
[日付期間の重複チェック](https://qiita.com/yaju/items/a58a78f41ee41258a5fe)
[2つの期間が重なり合うかどうかを判定する。](http://koseki.hatenablog.com/entry/20111021/range)
[Pythonで多重ループ（ネストしたforループ）からbreak](https://note.nkmk.me/python-break-nested-loops/)

for のネストは深くなりますが、1件毎のID比較が省略されるので少しは効率が上がるかも。

- DataFrame1を'ID' でグルーピングし、以下を ID 毎に処理する
- DataFrame2から同じ ID のデータを抽出する
- DataFrame1の各データを中間ループ、同IDで抽出したDataFrame2のデータを内側ループとし、参考記事の方法で重複チェック
- 重複があれば結果リストにID追加処理を行い、中間ループもbreakして次のIDの処理に行く

以下になります。

```
result_list = []
for ID, grp1 in df1.groupby('ID'):
  grp2 = df2[df2['ID'] == ID]
  for index1, item1 in grp1.iterrows():
    start1 = item1['start_date']
    end1   = item1['end_date']
    for index2, item2 in grp2.iterrows():
      if item2['start_date'] <= end1 and start1 <= item2['end_date']:
        result_list.append(ID)
        break
    else:
      continue
    break

print(result_list)
```

---

@Yuki Inoueさんの冒頭を見て「pandas for 遅い」で検索したら、たしかに色々あるようで、そういう主義にもなりますね。
メモ兼用として参考に置いておきます。
[pandas.DataFrame のforループをゆるふわ△改良して300倍高速化する](https://kunai-lab.hatenablog.jp/entry/2018/04/08/134924)
[うわっ…私のpandas、遅すぎ…?って時にやるべきこと（先人の知恵より）](https://shinyorke.hatenablog.com/entry/pandas-tips)
[pandasで1000万件のデータの前処理を高速にするTips集](https://qiita.com/kishiyama/items/b9d0a7ba3f03fd4089f3)
[pandasで複数カラムを参照して高速に1行1行値を調整する際のメモ](https://qiita.com/simonritchie/items/dd737a52cf32b662675c)
[pandas いかたこのたこつぼ](https://ikatakos.com/pot/programming/python/packages/pandas) / [PandasのDataFrameのappendの高速化](https://takazawa.github.io/hobby/pandas_append_fast/)
[python – Pandas：遅い日付変換](https://codeday.me/jp/qa/20190301/344891.html) / [遅いpandasのread_csvを高速化する方法(dask)](https://qiita.com/lucky0707/items/ff8ce66a40c492945229)
[今すぐ使えるpandas高速化テクニック](https://qiita.com/KTaskn/items/07e49a4f21e9afdad35f) / [Pandasでforループを回して処理する方法と注意点](https://deepage.net/features/pandas-iteration.html#for%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%82%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)
[Pythonの高速化のまとめ Ver.1](https://www.crz33.com/software/python/python_speedup) / [開発者がビッグデータ分析にPythonを使う時によくやる間違い](https://postd.cc/top-mistakes-python-big-data-analytics/)
[ISOに従っていないデータをpandas.to_datetime()すると500倍以上遅くなる可能性がある話とその対策](https://blog.ikedaosushi.com/entry/2018/10/03/033435)

---

**追記：&訂正**
実は性能は質問の処理が一番早かったですね。
あくまで質問のデータ件数・内容の条件です。10万件ならば全然変わるでしょう。
**計測の仕方を間違えていたので数値を訂正**

所要時間
質問:4.7ms前後, @kunif-1:20～21ms, @kunif-2:8ms前後, @Yuki Inoue:17.7ms前後 でした。

[Python プログラムの実行パフォーマンスを計測する](https://www.yoheim.net/blog.php?q=20171005) の「行ごとの処理時間を取得する」で、df1,df2を作成した後の処理部分を計測

メモリ使用増加量
質問:0.110MiB, @kunif-1:0.773MiB, @kunif-2:0.370～0.430MiB, @Yuki Inoue:0.797～0.812MiB でした。

同じ記事の「メモリの使用量を調べる」のmemory_profilerを使って、同様にdf1,df2を作成した後の処理部分を計測

Answer (score 0):

比較的ループ使わない感じで行ってみました。

1. `df1`, `df2` それぞれに `interval`項目を用意
2. `df1`, `df2` まとめた中で `ID`の一覧を用意 (今回のデータでは `1,2,3`になる)
3. それぞれの `ID`で, Seriesを作って (`iv1`, `iv2`) overlapしてるか確認

注意点？

- `ID`の一覧はループにしなくて構わないはず
- [pandas.Interval](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html) によると省略時は `closed=‘right’`で, 例えば `((1,3), (3,7))` の場合に 3はどちらに入るか。(問題になる場合もあるので)
- 結果は, (今のところ) listではなく表示のみにしている (Trueは 被ってる意味)

```py
import pandas as pd
data1 = [[1, "2010-01-01", "2010-01-20"], [1, "2010-03-20", "2010-03-30"],
        [2, "2010-02-01", "2010-04-20"], [3, "2010-06-10", "2010-06-15"],
        [3, "2010-06-20", "2010-06-30"], [3, "2010-07-10", "2010-07-20"]]

data2 = [[1, "2010-01-15", "2010-01-30"], [1, "2010-04-20", "2010-04-30"],
        [2, "2010-05-01", "2010-05-10"], [2, "2010-05-20", "2010-05-25"],
        [3, "2010-02-01", "2010-02-15"], [3, "2010-06-15", "2010-06-25"]]

columns1 = ["ID", "start_date", "end_date"]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, columns=columns1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2, columns=columns1)

for df in (df1, df2):
    df['interval'] = df.astype({'start_date': 'M8', 'end_date': 'M8'}).apply(
        lambda v: pd.Interval(v.start_date, v.end_date), axis=1)

for num in pd.unique(pd.concat([df1, df2]).ID):
    iv1, iv2 = [df.loc[df.ID == num, 'interval']for df in (df1, df2)]
    chk = iv2.map(pd.arrays.IntervalArray(iv1).overlaps)
    print(num, chk.map(any).any())

# 1 True
# 2 False
# 3 True
```

---

##### (追記)

`df1`, `df2` に項目追加するのではなく, (それぞれに) Seriesを用意する方法
処理の手順は元とほぼ変わらず

(`ID` が片側だけでなく両方に存在するなら, `iv2.index == iv.name` は `iv.name` だけで OK)

```py
iv1, iv2 = [df.astype({'start_date': 'M8', 'end_date': 'M8'})
              .apply(lambda v: [v.ID, pd.Interval(v.start_date, v.end_date)], axis=1, result_type='expand')
              .set_index(0)[1]   # 0,1 はそれぞれ ID, pd.Interval
                    for df in (df1, df2)]

res = iv1.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda iv:
    iv2[iv2.index == iv.name].map(pd.arrays.IntervalArray(iv).overlaps)
                             .map(any).any())
res.index[res].to_list()
# [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

ID毎に総当たりで比較。

参考：
[【Python】ふたつの配列からすべての組み合わせを評価](https://kaisk.hatenadiary.com/entry/2014/11/05/041011)

```
import numpy as np

data1 = [[1, "2010-01-01", "2010-01-20"], [1, "2010-03-20", "2010-03-30"],
        [2, "2010-02-01", "2010-04-20"], [3, "2010-06-10", "2010-06-15"],
        [3, "2010-06-20", "2010-06-30"], [3, "2010-07-10", "2010-06-20"]]

data2 = [[1, "2010-01-15", "2010-01-30"], [1, "2010-04-20", "2010-04-30"],
        [2, "2010-05-01", "2010-05-10"], [2, "2010-05-20", "2010-05-25"],
        [3, "2010-02-01", "2010-02-15"], [3, "2010-06-15", "2010-06-25"]]

arr1 = np.array(data1)
arr2 = np.array(data2)

result_list = []

for id in np.unique(arr1[:,0]):
    _arr2 = arr2[arr2[:,0] == id]
    if len(_arr2) == 0:
        continue
    _arr1 = arr1[arr1[:,0] == id]
    xx = np.array([[x for x in _arr1] for _ in range(len(_arr2))]).reshape(-1,3)
    yy = np.array([[y for _ in range(len(_arr1))] for y in _arr2]).reshape(-1,3)
    if np.any((xx[:,1] <= yy[:,2]) & (yy[:,1] <= xx[:,2])):
        result_list.append(id)
```